# Purpose of the "How do you get to West Egg village?" scene in "The Great Gatsby"

Tags: f-scott-fitzgerald, the-great-gatsby

In *The Great Gatsby*, Nick is asked by a traveller, "How do you get to West Egg village?" and then Nick writes that after that moment he felt like an original settler of West Egg.

> It was lonely for a day or so until one morning some man, more recently arrived than I, stopped me on the road.
>
> “How do you get to West Egg village?” he asked helplessly.
>
> I told him. And as I walked on I was lonely no longer. I was a guide, a pathfinder, an original settler. He had casually conferred on me the freedom of the neighbourhood.
>
> And so with the sunshine and the great bursts of leaves growing on the trees, just as things grow in fast movies, I had that familiar conviction that life was beginning over again with the summer.
>
> ([F. Scott Fitzgerald, *The Great Gatsby*, Chapter 1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/64317/64317-h/64317-h.htm#chapter-1).)

What is the purpose of this scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows that he is becoming habituated to the place:  he is no longer a newcomer who needs directions, but an inhabitant who can give them.  It inspires a poetic flight of fancy because that means a lot to him.

This is particularly important because the conclusion of the novel is when he decides this is a bad place for him to live, and to move back to the Midwest.